# Normal map baked in Marmoset has artifacts when imported to blender

Tags: normals, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

Made a high and low poly models in blender and exported them to Marmoset for baking

First picture is how it looks in Marmoset, ok for the most part

Second photo is the same texture imported onto the same mesh in blender, it has these weird artifacts on flat parts of it
[image: Marmoset bake looks fine for the most part]
[image: But in Blender in looks like this]

Mesh looks like this:
[image]

I have tried adding additional edges like this and it eliminated the problem but creates another one...
[image]

Here the picture is with these edges, it makes spaces around corners look bend

Marmoset render still looks fine, as if these edges were not there (they are)

[image]

I have tried changing settings in marmoset
I have also tried inverting green channel
Artifacts are showing in Cycles, Eevee and material view about the same

Some help or pointers would be appreciated

Comment: Your screenshot shows that the original edges are marked as seams (red color) I guess for UV unwrapping. Probably they are also marked sharp (blue/cyan) but this is not visible because of the red markings. When you have inset the edges, they inherit these seam and sharp marks, so I would recommend you select the new inner edge, then either from the _Edge_ menu on top or pressing Ctrl+E for the edge context menu you choose _Clear Sharp_ to get rid of it. And by the way, on the holes at the front you've inset too far, there you have overlapping faces which is not good.

Comment: I forgot to mention it but there are no sharp edges here, but after cleaning the new edges from uv seams, the issue didn't went away.

Comment: Then it's hard to tell what else could be the problem without checking your file. But as I mentioned, the overlapping faces are not good for shading either.

Comment: Did you set the color mode of your normal map image node to non-color?